# Intent, as well as suggested file paths, is null

Tags: android

So i'm doing simple operation for getting video from camera:

```
            Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            mVideoFileUri = getOutputMediaFile(); // create a file to save the video in specific folder
            if(mVideoFileUri != null) {
                takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mVideoFileUri);
            }
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

For almoust all of my testing devices this works fine, but on `Samsung galaxy S4` it goes like this:

```
    @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    String videoPath;
                    if(mVideoFileUri != null) {
                        videoPath = mVideoFileUri.getPath();
                    } else {
                        Uri videoUri = data.getData();
                        videoPath = KovlaApplication.POST_KITKAT_SDK ? PostKitKatFilePathHelper.getPath(getActivity(), videoUri)
                                : getRealPathFromURI(videoUri);
            }
    }
```

The thing is that here both `data` and `mVideoFileUri` are null, therefore it's not working.

**I realized that if i'm taking away EXTRA_OUTPUT it works, but in this case it's not working for other devices**

Comment: On my old motorola there was an issue with lack of RAM, I was starting Camera intent, took photo, during this app was killed and then recreated without knowledge of camera intent result. I ended up requesting camera intent with certain path saving it before call, if app was killed and i had saved path if not i was clearing saved path i onresult

Comment: It works on my S4, but it ignores the `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: @MikeM. , thx for response, what do you mean by ignoring? Code stays the same but onResult file becomes null and data isn't?

Comment: It stores the video in the Media Provider, and returns the URI in `data.getData()`.